# Emulating python msvcrt module's kbhit() on Unix

Tags: python, unix, tty

I am trying to write python code for Unix/Posix systems that emulates the `kbhit()` and `getch()` functions in the Windows `msvcrt` module.  There's actually a few solutions online on how to do this; my problem is that none of the `kbhit` solutions I've found (even on stackoverflow) work correctly for me.

I will explain in more detail:

Basically, the code to emulate `getch` is straightforward:

```
def getch():
   ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
   return ch
```

And the code to emulate `kbhit` is... well... simple enough using the `select` module:

```
def kbhit():
    results = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return results[0] != []
```

However, as programmers who've tried to read one character at a time have eventually discovered, you need to set your terminal settings to allow for unbuffered input.  Usually something like this is used before calling `getch()` or `kbhit()`:

```
import os, select, sys, termios

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)  # (For restoring later.)

# Create new unbufferd terminal settings to use:
new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)
```

At exit, we can use something like this to restore the old terminal settings:

```
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)
```

The problem with this is that occasionally the `kbhit()` function returns `False` even when there is input waiting to be read.

To demonstrate, I've created a proof-of-concept program that you can run yourself (on a Unix/Posix) system to see the problem first-hand:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# File:  proof-of-concept-kbhit.py


import atexit
import os
import select
import sys
import termios
import time


def getch():
   ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
   return ch


def kbhit():
    results = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return results[0] != []


def main():
    # Save the terminal settings:
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    # Create new unbufferd terminal settings to use:
    new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)

    # Reset original terminal settings on exit:
    atexit.register(termios.tcsetattr, fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)

    seconds_to_wait = 10
    print()
    print(f"Type a short word or phrase in the next {seconds_to_wait} seconds.")
    print("(Your typed letters will not show up right away; don't stop typing.)")
    print(flush=True)
    while True:
        print(f" >>> Seconds left to wait:  {seconds_to_wait} \r", end='', flush=True)
        if seconds_to_wait <= 0:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds_to_wait -= 1

    print()
    print()
    print('Now your typed letters will be retrieved\n'
          'and printed at a rate of one per second.')
    print('A dot (".") should also print out every second,\n'
          'whether you type anything or not.')
    print('(Hit CTRL-C to exit this program.)')
    print(flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.', end='', flush=True)
        if kbhit():
            ch = getch()
            print('\n', ch, sep='', end='', flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To see the problem I'm seeing, simply run this program on a Unix/Posix system.  You will immediately prompted to type a short word or phrase in the next ten seconds.  Then:

1. Type <kbd>Hello, world</kbd> (or simply <kbd>Hello</kbd>).  (You don't need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)
2. Wait out the ten seconds.
3. You will see text that tells you that the program will then begin to print out your text one letter at a time, at a rate of one letter per second.
4. Watch as the letter `H` gets printed.
5. Note that no other letters get printed, even after ten seconds or more.  (The dots are still printing at the rate of one dot per second, but there are no letters being printed.)
6. Now, press the letter <kbd>z</kbd>.
7. Note that the remaining letters you typed (that is, `ello, world`) start showing up, including the <kbd>z</kbd> you typed in the previous step.
8. If you are able to quickly type three `w`s in a row (that is, <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>) between two printings of `.`, then you will see that only one of the `w`s is picked up, while the others are temporarily ignored.
9. Press any other letter (for example, <kbd>g</kbd>) to see the other two `w`s reported, as well as that `g`.

What's going on?

The documentation for `select.select` says that `select.select()` will return any given file descriptors in the first argument that have input waiting to be read (more specifically, that are "ready for reading").

For whatever reason, the code `results = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)` keeps setting `results[0]` to an empty list, even though `ello, world` is still waiting to be read.

And `ello, world` is still indeed in there, as evidenced by the fact that pressing an additional letter will cause `ello, world` to be detected and printed out.

As far as I can tell, `getch()` is working correctly; it's `kbhit()` that is incorrectly returning `False` when input is waiting.

Does anyone know why `kbhit()` (or, rather, the `select()` call inside it) is failing to detect the `ello, world` waiting to be read?  Does anyone know how to fix this?  (I wonder if it's some terminal setting that I haven't specified correctly.)

(I ran this program on a Linux platform, on MacOS, and a NetBSD platform, and the program had the same issue on all three platforms.)

---

Addendum (2023-02-13):

Just to make sure it's clear, I want my emulated `kbhit()` function to be non-blocking, just like the `kbhit()` function in the `msvcrt` Python module for Windows.

In other words, if input is waiting, it should immediately return True.  But it there is no input waiting, it should immediately return False, without blocking to wait for input to arrive.

And to verify that `kbhit()` is non-blocking, you should see dots (".") print out every second, continuously, whether or not there is input waiting.  So if you leave the program alone, you should see a continuous stream of dots, like:

```
.............................
```

(If you fail to see this growing stream of dots, it probably means that `kbhit()` is blocking execution while it waits for keyboard input.  This blocking behavior is not what I want, as `msvcrt.kbhit()` is not a blocking call.)

This is my proof of concept code that uses GIZ's code for the `kbhit()` function.  As I've stated as a comment in his reply, when I run this the `kbhit()` function blocks, so if there's no input waiting, the program will freeze until new input is made.  However, GIZ says that when tested, the code does not freeze for him/her.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# File:  proof-of-concept-kbhit-using-fcntl.py


import atexit
import fcntl
import os
import select
import struct
import sys
import termios
import time


def getch():
   ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
   return ch

# This old function has been replaced by the newer function that follows.
def kbhit_old():
    results = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return results[0] != []

# This is the newer function that is replacing the older function above.
def kbhit():
   return bool(fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdin.fileno(), termios.FIONREAD, struct.pack('I', 0)))

def main():
    # Save the terminal settings:
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    # Create new unbufferd terminal settings to use:
    new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)

    # Reset original terminal settings on exit:
    atexit.register(termios.tcsetattr, fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)

    seconds_to_wait = 10
    print()
    print(f"Type a short word or phrase in the next {seconds_to_wait} seconds.")
    print("(Your typed letters will not show up right away; don't stop typing.)")
    print(flush=True)
    while True:
        print(f" >>> Seconds left to wait:  {seconds_to_wait} \r", end='', flush=True)
        if seconds_to_wait <= 0:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds_to_wait -= 1

    print()
    print()
    print('Now your typed letters will be retrieved\n'
          'and printed at a rate of one per second.')
    print('A dot (".") should also print out every second,\n'
          'whether you type anything or not.')
    print('(Hit CTRL-C to exit this program.)')
    print(flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.', end='', flush=True)
        if kbhit():
            ch = getch()
            print('\n', ch, sep='', end='', flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If anyone wants to test this code to see if `kbhit()` freezes for them (and then report back as a comment), maybe we can figure out why we're seeing differences.

---

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As I have speculated, the problem is within your `khbit` function. Avoid using `select` the Linux manual page already warns against it:

[`select(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

> **WARNING:** `select()` can monitor only file descriptors numbers that
> are less than `FD_SETSIZE` (1024)—an unreasonably low limit for
> many modern applications—and this limitation will not change.
> All modern applications should instead use `poll(2)` or `epoll(7)`,
> which do not suffer this limitation.

Preferably using `fcntl.ioctl` to know if there's any data to be read from `stdin` (your keyboard):

```
def kbhit(): 
   return bool(fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdin.fileno(), termios.FIONREAD, struct.pack('I', 0)))
```

`ioctl` takes three arguments:

The first argument `filenno` which is the file descriptor. The second argument  `termios.FIONREAD` which is a flag to specify the kind of operation you want to perform on the specified file descriptor, from the manual page of [`ioctl_tty(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) :

> `FIONREAD` Get the number of bytes in the input buffer

and a third argument `struct.pack('I', 0)` is used to pack the integer value 0 into a binary string. This value is passed as the third argument to the `ioctl` function and specifies the size of the buffer to be used to return the result of the request. In this case, the buffer is exactly 4 bytes long, which is the size of an `unsigned int` on most systems. The packed binary string is used to pass the buffer size to the `ioctl` function, so it knows how much memory to allocate for the result.

Simply put, we're checking if `sys.stdin.buffer` contains data or not, if it has data ready to be read, we go ahead and read it character by character.

### Edited:

And you need to edit your `getch` function to make to make it none blocking:

```
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    # fetch stdin's old flags
    old_flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    # set the none-blocking flag 
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, old_flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    except:
        ch = None
    finally:
        # resetting stdin to default falgs
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, old_flags)
    return ch
```

We're setting the `os.O_NONBLOCK` none-blocking stream flag and trying to read one character at each call, if the buffer is empty  the function returns `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @GIZ.  I replaced my version of `kbhit` with yours, and now `Hello, world` get printed out a letter at a time (as expected).  However, the new version of `kbhit` is now a blocking call, in that if I don't hit any keys, no dots are printed out.  (Previously, a dot was printed out every second, regardless of whether or not any letters were typed.)  Do you know how to make your `kbhit` code non-blocking?  (Just so you know, I tested your `kbhit` code on Linux, MacOS, and a NetBSD, and it behaves the same on all three platforms.)

Comment: @J-L the `kbhit` function here doesn't block your stream, that's if there are any characters in the buffer they will be printed or  the loop will continue and `.` will be printed after sleeping for 1 second. I tested the code on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS from the terminal and works fine for me. Not sure if this is a configuration issue on your system.

Comment: Thanks for testing, @GIZ.  Just to make sure we're running the exact same code, I put my code with your change in the ADDENDUM section of my post above.  Could you run that code as-is and see if it blocks for you or not?  (It's still blocking for me.)  Thanks, and I appreciate your input!

Comment: ...or perhaps you could paste the contents of the script you used, so I can see if it runs the same way on my platforms?

Comment: @J-L My bad, sorry! I edited `getch` function in my code and just noticed this now. Your `getch` function does block the stream. Please have a look at the **Edited** section in my answer. Best of luck!